# How can Sam Wilson fulfill his future role?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the end of *Avengers: Endgame*, Sam Wilson is chosen as the

> next Captain America.

I understand WHY he is chosen. Bucky is mentally damaged and can be easily manipulated by Hydra. But Sam is a mere mortal.

> He wasn't injected with any kind of serum like Steve. Unless they plan to inject Sam with some hormones, what makes him the next Cap?

Comment: He's got a boss shield and a snazzy outfit.

Comment: I thought this question was about Sam Wilson's ass...

Comment: @Valorum You mean in the "Here's your gun, you're in the army now" fashion?

Answer (score 24):

Captain America isn’t about being a super soldier and being able to kick ass because of how powerful you are. It is about standing up for what is right, helping out everyone no matter the cost. Incidentally this is also why Steve in *Avengers: Endgame*

> Is worthy of Mjolnir.

This is in part why Sam was chosen over Bucky because he shares Steve’s ideals and morals and wants to do what’s right.

And even if we look past that, Sam as the Falcon can hold his own quite well being able to fly and all has some serious advantages. Add the shield in to the mix and he has some serious power as a fighter. He doesn’t necessarily need the super soldier serum, he is an Avenger without it after all.

Comment: In reference to the spoiler tag, Sam should then be able to do the same, to really fulfill this role, no?

Answer (score 12):

In the first *Captain America* movie, a frail Steve Rogers also asked why he was the one being chosen. Yes, I know your question is technically not about the *why*, but the answer Erskine gave him still stands...

> ROGERS: Can I ask a question?
>
> ERSKINE: Just one?
>
> ROGERS: Why me? [...]
>
> ERSKINE: [...] But more important, the man. **The serum amplifies everything that is inside, so good becomes great; bad becomes worse. This is why you were chosen. Because the strong man who has known power all his life, may lose respect for that power, but a weak man knows the value of strength, and knows... compassion.**
>
> ROGERS: Thanks. I think.
>
> ERSKINE: *[Gesturing toward the wine]* Get it, get it. Whatever happens tomorrow, you must promise me one thing. That you will stay who you are, not a perfect soldier, but a good man.

Sam Wilson, while not necessarily a "weak man", does qualify for the role - see his "good actions", good heart etc throughout the MCU. As @TheLethalCarrot noted, he's a decent fighter to begin with - and comics-wise, Sam Wilson as Captain America in *All-New Captan America*  was holding his own nicely (with no serum involved, IIRC).

And in case he needs the occasional amp-up, he's friends with gods, superpowered people, the Sorcerer Supreme, Professor Hulk and all eight of his PHDs - he'll be fine.

Comment: Has Sam actually ever met Thor or the Sorcerer Supreme besides fighting alongside them at the end of *Endgame*?

Comment: @MartianInvader probably not, but in later movies, they might partner up more regularly

Comment: @MartianInvader At the end of Age of Ultron all the avengers are at the compound, including Thor (the "elevator is not worthy" scene). Thor is there for a while and Falcon is often shown at the Avengers compound, for example when Ant-Man snuck in. It is reasonable to assume Sam met Thor at that time.

Comment: A man without a super-solider serum *really* knows the value of a good shield.

Answer (score 5):

Sam Wilson [became Captain America in the comics](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Samuel_Wilson_(Earth-616)#Becoming_Captain_America). While he did have a superpower there, that superpower was telepathy of and control of birds so it's not exactly a substitute for a super soldier serum. He seems to have done perfectly fine there.

In the MCU, there are numerous other superheroes that are just regular people, who just have very good training or technologically advanced equipment: Black Widow, Hawkeye, Iron Man, Ant Man, etc. Sam Wilson has the equipment (the wings and drone) and the training (military).

It's possible that the Disney+ Series [Falcon & Winter Soldier](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Falcon_%26_Winter_Soldier) will cover how he does in his new role, but for now we have too little information about it to even say when it takes place.